# Add and retrieve Key Value pair from table

Tags: c#, collections

I have a (read only) table containing some config info, for example:

```
Red  -  1,
Green - 2,
Orange - 3.
```

What is the easiest way to load this into some collection, so that I can write, for example:

```
byte x = MyColl.Red;
```

Comment: What kind of table you have? Is it DataTable class, or table in database, or html table?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

> The enum keyword is used to declare an enumeration, a distinct type
>   that consists of a set of named constants called the enumerator list.

The problem with this is that it needs to be hard coded at compile time, so reading it from a table will not make sense.

The other option would be tio use [Dictionary Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

> Represents a collection of keys and values.

where you could look at

```
Dictionary<string, byte>
```

So as to use it such that

```
byte x = MyCollDictionary["Red"];
```